# Unsupported operand in if/else statement error in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am a newbie to Python, what am I doing wrong?

```
if p1_teller == 0 & p1_raw[0:1] != "/":
    print "Loop 1"
else:
    print "Loop 2"
```

Then I get the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Use `and` instead of `&`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python uses `and` for logical and. `&` is a [bitwise and](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_AND#AND). Change your code to:

```
if p1_teller == 0 and p1_raw[0:1] != "/":
    print "Loop 1"
else:
    print "Loop 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

A brief google search shows python using 'and' for its operator, not &

Comment: you can use & in python also, it just doesn't mean the same thing and is not applicable in this case

Answer (score 0):

Use `and` instead of `&`
change this :

```
if p1_teller == 0 & p1_raw[0:1] != "/":
```

to :

```
if p1_teller == 0 and p1_raw[0:1] != "/":
```